# Why doesn't ([A-Z]|[0-9])[\\.a-zA-Z0-9_-]{0,}$ match abc123 in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression for the following rule.

RegEx: `([A-Z]|[0-9])[\\.a-zA-Z0-9_-]{0,}$`

Rule: Combination of letters, hyphen and dash, also must contains upper case letter or number.

When I try the string `abc123`, it matches as expected on the [JavaScript Regular Expression Tester](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html).

But it failed in Java code:

```
str.matches("([A-Z]|[0-9])[\\.a-zA-Z0-9_-]{0,}$")
```

Any people know the reason? Is it something to do with my reg ex string?

Comment: 2 things: a) The regex does not describe the Rule you have, b) don't escape the ``.`` with a ``\``, the dot does not need to be escaped in character classes (=when between ``[`` and ``]``).

Comment: `([A-Z]|[0-9])` can be written as `([A-Z0-9])` (or even  `[A-Z0-9]` if you don't need the backreference).

Comment: Thanks guys, does this one look right? - added restriction that it can only be started with letters, and length is between 8 - 18. 
^[a-zA-Z]((?=.*\\d)|(?=.*[A-Z]))[a-zA-Z0-9\\-_\\.]{7,17}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point is that you do not match the complete string but only part "123". Contrary [`String.matches`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) only yields true if the complete string matches.

Note: Your regular expression is not similar to your description. It matches strings that *start* with upper case letter of number.